# How to add error bars to a fit function in Mathematica 10?

Tags: plotting

My professor gave us the following code to fit a Lorentzian to our data. I want to add vertical error bars (with individual error found in the experiment) to the plot but I don't know how. Any suggestions and related material would be appreciated!

```
    Clear[a, b, c, f]

    Rdata = {{1, 8.404}, {9, 11.312}, {16, 53.500}, {17, 57.308}, {18, 
57.491}, {19, 7.315}, {36, 2.450}, {54, 0.182}, {90, 2.787}, {180,
 2.634}};
    Rdataerror = {{{1, 8.404}, 0.003}, {{9, 11.312}, 
0.011}, {{16, 53.500}, 0.556}, {{17, 57.308}, 
0.770}, {{18, 57.491}, 1.220}, {{19, 7.315}, 4.926}, {{36, 2.450},
 0.056}, {{54, 0.149}, 1.6}, {{90, 2.787}, 0.0718}, {{180, 2.634},
 0.512}};


    phidata = {{1, 0.007}, {9, 0.03}, {16, -0.125}, {17, -0.29}, {18, 
0.82}, {19, -4.432}, {36, 3.08}, {54, -1.94}, {90, -1.45}, {180, -2.39}};

    phidataerror = {{{1, 0.007}, 0.005}, {{9, 0.03}, 
0.002}, {{16, -0.125}, 0.003}, {{17, -0.29}, 0.031}, {{18, 0.82}, 
0.1}, {{19, -4.432}, 1}, {{36, 3.08}, 0.04}, {{54, -1.94}, 
1.6}, {{90, -1.45}, 0.12}, {{180, -2.39}, 0.39}};


    FindFit[Rdata, a/Sqrt[(f^2 - b^2)^2 + f^2 c^2], {a, {b, 2}, {c, 56}}, f]

    disp[f_] = a/Sqrt[(f^2 - b^2)^2 + f^2 c^2] /. %;


    phi[f_] = Piecewise[{{Pi - ArcTan[c f/(f^2 - b^2)], -c f/(f^2 - b^2) < 
   0}}, -ArcTan[c f/(f^2 - b^2)]] /. %%;


    Show[Plot[disp[f], {f, 0, 60}, PlotRange -> {0, 80}], ListPlot[Rdata],AxesLabel -> {"f (Hz)", "amplitude ratio R"}]


    Show[Plot[disp[f], {f, 100, 600}, PlotRange -> {0, 3}], ListPlot[Rdata], AxesLabel -> {"f (Hz)", "amplitude ratio R"}]


    Show[Plot[phi[f], {f, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> {0, 3.2}], ListPlot[phidata], AxesLabel -> {"f (Hz)", "- (delta phi)"}]

    Show[Plot[phi[f], {f, 15, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 3.2}], ListPlot[phidata], AxesLabel -> {"f (Hz)", "- (delta phi)"}]
```

Comment: As I put together my answer, and looking at the graph of Rdata: Is there also error in the x-direction? This might be the case, or the fitting function might be suboptimal.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, I try to give some different options on displaying error (besides the obvious [Error Bar Package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ErrorBarPlots/guide/ErrorBarPlottingPackage.html)):

1. Generate the minimum and maximum datapoints:
   `RdataLow=MapThread[{#1[\[1\]], #1[\[2\]] - .5 #2[\[2\]]} &, {Rdata, Rdataerror}];
   RdataHigh=MapThread[{#1[\[1\]], #1[\[2\]] + .5 #2[\[2\]]} &, {Rdata, Rdataerror}];`
2. Then, find fits for all datapoints (min, ideal, max) at once:
   `fits = FindFit[#, a/Sqrt[(f^2 - b^2)^2 + f^2 c^2], {a, {b, 2}, {c, 56}}, 
   f] & /@ {Rdata, RdataLow, RdataHigh}`
3. And finally: Plot all of them at once:
   `Plot[Evaluate[a/Sqrt[(f^2 - b^2)^2 + f^2 c^2] /. fits], (* ... *), Filling -> {2 -> {3}}]`

Of course, you could also just `Show` multiple plots at once, e.g. a `ListPlot` of the errors *together* with the original plots. Or you could just display the error values by using the `Epilog:>{}` option within one of your plot commands like so:

```
Plot[(* ... *), Epilog :> {Text[#[[2]], #[[1]]] & /@ Rdataerror}]
```

Same goes for the vertical error bars: You would in that case just use `Line`, not `Text`, using the low and high datasets created before, which, all combined, results in:

```
Plot[Evaluate[a/Sqrt[(f^2 - b^2)^2 + f^2 c^2] /. fits], {f, 0, 80}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Filling -> {2 -> {3}}, 
 Epilog :> {{PointSize[Large], Blue, 
    Point /@ Rdata}, {Thickness[Large], Red, 
    MapThread[Line[{#1, #2}] &, {RdataLow, RdataHigh}]}}]
```

[image: the whole plot]

Comment: I got a function value error? and invalid variables?

Comment: @DanielSchulze: What do you mean by that? Of course, the quality of the fit depends on the function you want to fit for.

Comment: And the fitting method itself.

Comment: I am still having trouble understanding the code and the error message that the program is giving me.

Comment: @DanielSchulze: What error message?

Comment: @DanielSchulze: Ah, found it: Stackexchange's formatter changed some code into a link. I fixed that. Try again.

Comment: thank you for being extremely diligent in your willingness to help one individual use mathematica. Are there good tutorials online/included with the program? Also a bit off topic: what software would you suggest for doing lab reports (I like the way LaTeX looks, really crisp math, but I don't know if it is the right tool for the job)?

Comment: @DanielSchulze: Did you ever try pressing F1 in *Mathematica*? There is extensive online help, tutorials etc. built-in. You can copy *Mathematica* output in $\TeX$-format and reuse it within LaTeX documents. As for "doing lab reports": *Mathematica* can certainly do that. You might want to sift through the widths and breadths of this forum here to find a multitude of examples.